# Facebook "hijacks" my Android app when I post a link to it

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I use an `Intent` (`ACTION_SEND` with a Facebook Open Graph link as the text) to fire up the Facebook app and allow a user to fire off a Facebook status update.

This works fine, except for in one single circumstance: if the user's session has expired in the Facebook app, the Facebook app asks them to log in again, and then forgets that it was mid-flow within my app. It just drops the user into the main Facebook home page, "stacked on top" of my app, if you see what I mean.

At this point, my user can't do anything with my app. The Back button won't go back to my Activity; it only goes back as far as the Facebook app's home page. If they leave my app and return to it, they're dropped back into Facebook's homepage. The only way out seems to be to force-quit and restart my app, at which point everything returns to normal.

Is there anything I can do about this "hijacking" of my app by Facebook? Obviously I don't want it to happen at all, but as a minimum it would be nice to be able to detect that it had happened when my app was re-opened and drop back to one of my own activities...

(Yes, I know I *could* use the Facebook SDK within my app, but it's complicated and annoying and fraught with problems, and the reason I'm trying this alternative is because when I was using it my users were telling me that their status updates weren't showing up anyway, despite it always working for me in testing...)

Comment: "The Back button won't go back to my Activity; it only goes back as far as the Facebook app's home page" -- and if they press BACK there, what happens? "If they leave my app and return to it" -- how are they leaving and how are they returning? Do you mean something like pressing HOME to leave and returning to your app via the overview (a.k.a., recent-tasks) screen?

Comment: @commonsware If they press BACK from the Facebook home screen, nothing happens. They remain in Facebook. "If they leave my app and return to it"—yes, I mean exactly that; pressing home and returning to my app via recent tasks or launching it from Apps. (I *think* this is all exactly true, but it's very hard to reproduce, as I can't force my Facebook app session to expire. If I'm simply not logged in to Facebook, the flow works fine—Facebook returns me to my app after the Facebook login flow.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If they press BACK from the Facebook home screen, nothing happens. They remain in Facebook

Then your problem is that Facebook is evil. Blocking BACK entirely is user-hostile. Blocking BACK from an activity other than the task root is user-hostile and developer-hostile.

> Is there anything I can do about this "hijacking" of my app by Facebook?

Launch it in a separate task, using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` on the `Intent` that you use to pass control to Facebook. Its back stack will be decoupled from yours, and the user should be able to return to your app via the overview screen.

The downside is that the user *has* to return to your app via the overview screen (or by tapping on your launcher icon again, or similar means). This will be even for the cases that work right now, as pressing BACK will land the user at the home screen eventually, instead of your app.

Comment: Thank you. I'm tempted to launch as-is: maybe I'm worrying too much about something that's unlikely to happen in the real world. (How many people who use Facebook are going to have the app sitting there with an expired session, I wonder? It happened on every device for me, but that's because they're test hardware that's been sitting around powered off for a month!) If I start getting bug reports, I'll use your suggestion.